# two modals pop up when one button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have two buttons on my screen that open up the same modal. However when i click one of the buttons, both modals pop up, one behind each other, when i only want one. I think the problem is that the javascript is iterating over every modal with the class `.modal__cancel-appointment`. However im not sure how to change the javascript in order to only open up one model.

```html
(function ($, _) {
  'use strict'

  window.HERO = window.HERO || {}
  window.HERO.modals = window.HERO.modals || {}

  // CANCEL APPOINTMENT MODAL
  var CancelAppointmentModal = _.assign(
    Object.create(window.HERO.modals.Base),
    {
      addEventListeners: function () {
        this.$el
          .on('click', '.keep-appointment-button', this.close.bind(this))
          .on('click', '.cancel-appointment-button', this.cancelAppointment.bind(this))
      },

      cancelAppointment: function (evt) {
        var $button = $(evt.currentTarget)
        this.disableActions()
        $button.text($button.data('disable-with'))

        $.get($button.data('path'))
          .done(function (data) {
            Turbolinks.visit(data.redirect_to)
          }).fail(function (data) {
            console.error('Call to ' + evt.currentTarget.href + ' failed')
            Turbolinks.visit(data.redirect_to)
          })
      },

      disableActions: function () {
        this.$('.cancel-appointment-button').attr('disabled', true)
      }
    }
  )

  function initModals () {
    var $modals = $('.modal__cancel-appointment')
    $modals.each(function (index) {
      Object.create(CancelAppointmentModal).init($modals.eq(index))
    })
  }

  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', initModals)
})(
  window.jQuery,
  window._
)
```

This is the top of my model:

```html
  <div class="modal modal__cancel-appointment"
    data-test-modal="cancel-appointment"
    data-width="540"
    data-modal-control=<%= "[data-modal-control='.modal__cancel-appointment-#{appointment.id}']" %>>
```

```html
 <%= button_tag t("common.cancel_title"),
                              type: "button",
                              class: "dropdown-element cancel-appointment-dropdown-button",
                              data: { "modal-control" => ".modal__cancel-appointment-#{appointment.id}" } %>
              <%= render "shared/modal_cancel_appointment", appointment: appointment, invoice: invoice %>
```

```html
                <%= button_tag "Cancel Appointment",
                                type: "button",
                                class: "hero-button hero-button--invoices",
                                data: { "modal-control" => ".modal__cancel-appointment-#{@appointment.id}" } %>

                <%= render "shared/modal_cancel_appointment", appointment: invoice.appointment, invoice: @invoice %>
```

Comment: Modals by design are singular and center of the screen. Maybe you load the modal which then hosts two pages inside as 50% iframes or write custom code to show to modal boxes.

Comment: ive made my question more clear. I only want one model to appear.

Comment: you could create a show modal function that shows only one window, and if its already showing, dont show the next window